# Cannot run Pit Ideea Plugin with Junit5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5, mutation-testing

I have a project with Java11 and Junit5 and cannot run PIT Mutation testing via InteliJ plugin.

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.util.PitError: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally. Please check the classpath and/or enable test plugin for used test tool.

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : AdoptOpenJDK
Version : 11.0.6+10
Uptime : 694
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=51955:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin
 2 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
BootClassPathSupported : false
```

I have the latest version of IDEA: 2020.2.3, and of course the latest PIT plugin: 1.4.4. The plugin contains the fix for running PIT with Junit5.

I run PIT from: Edit Configurations -> PIT Runner.

I am using maven, so in my pom I have dependencies for Junit:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tried it also with junit version 5.7.0 ... the same

Comment: Probably you should report an issue to plugin vendor: https://github.com/mjedynak/pit-idea-plugin/issues